# Hibernate Search behaves differently between DEV and PROD with same databse

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I have one domain object that needs to be indexed by Hibernate Search.  When I do a FullTextQuery on this object on my DEV machine, I get the expected results.  I then deploy the app to a WAR and explode it to my PROD server (a VPS).  When I perform the same "search" on my PROD machine, I don't get the expected results at all (it seems like some results are missing).

I've run LUKE to ensure that everything was properly indexed, and it appears that everything is where it should be... I'm new to Hibernate Search, so any help would be appreciated.

Here's my domain Object:

```
package com.chatter.domain;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.apache.solr.analysis.LowerCaseFilterFactory;
import org.apache.solr.analysis.SnowballPorterFilterFactory;
import org.apache.solr.analysis.StandardTokenizerFactory;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.AnalyzerDef;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.IndexedEmbedded;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Parameter;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Store;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.TokenFilterDef;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.TokenizerDef;

@Entity
@Table(name="faq")
@Indexed()
@AnalyzerDef(name = "customanalyzer",
tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
filters = {
  @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
  @TokenFilterDef(factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class, params = {
    @Parameter(name = "language", value = "English")
  })
})
public class CustomerFaq implements Comparable<CustomerFaq>
{
  private Long id;
  @IndexedEmbedded
  private Customer customer;
  @Field(index=Index.TOKENIZED, store=Store.NO)
  private String question;
  @Field(index=Index.TOKENIZED, store=Store.NO)
  private String answer;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  public Long getId()
  {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(Long id)
  {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
  public Customer getCustomer()
  {
    return customer;
  }
  public void setCustomer(Customer customer)
  {
    this.customer = customer;
  }

  @Column(name="question", length=1500)
  public String getQuestion()
  {
    return question;
  }
  public void setQuestion(String question)
  {
    this.question = question;
  }

  @Column(name="answer", length=1500)
  public String getAnswer()
  {
    return answer;
  }
  public void setAnswer(String answer)
  {
    this.answer = answer;
  }
  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj)
  {
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
    CustomerFaq other = (CustomerFaq) obj;
    if (id == null)
    {
      if (other.id != null) return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id)) return false;
    return true;
  }
  @Override
  public int compareTo(CustomerFaq o)
  {
    if (this.getCustomer().equals(o.getCustomer()))
    {
      return this.getId().compareTo(o.getId());
    }
    else
    {
      return this.getCustomer().getId().compareTo(o.getCustomer().getId());
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a snippet of my Customer domain object:

```
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Store;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
// ... other imports

@Entity
public class Customer
{
  @Field(index=Index.TOKENIZED, store=Store.YES)
  private Long id;

  // ... other instance vars

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  public Long getId()
  {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(Long id)
  {
    this.id = id;
  }
```

And my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <!-- Hibernate Search configuration -->
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider"
                value="filesystem" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="C:/lucene/indexes" />


        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And finally, here's the query that's being used in a DAO:

```
public List<CustomerFaq> searchFaqs(String question, Customer customer)
  {
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(CustomerFaq.class).get();
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("question", "answer").matching(question).createQuery();

    org.hibernate.Query fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, CustomerFaq.class);

    List<CustomerFaq> matchingQuestionsList = fullTextQuery.list();
    log.debug("Found " + matchingQuestionsList.size() + " matching questions");
    List<CustomerFaq> list = new ArrayList<CustomerFaq>();
    for (CustomerFaq customerFaq : matchingQuestionsList)
    {
      log.debug("Comparing " + customerFaq.getCustomer() + " to " + customer + " -> " + customerFaq.getCustomer().equals(customer));
      log.debug("Does list already contain this customer FAQ? " + list.contains(customerFaq));
      if (customerFaq.getCustomer().equals(customer) && !list.contains(customerFaq))
      {
        list.add(customerFaq);
      }
    }
    log.debug("Returning " + list.size() + " matching questions based on customer: " + customer);
    return list;
  }
```

Comment: there is of course no specific change in the Search code between prod/dev ? ;-)

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're deploying an updated WAR and you changed some indexing options (like an Analyzer) you might have to rebuild the index to re-synchronize with the database correctly.

Comment: There are no changes to the code base between dev and prod.  And as it stands right now, it re-indexes the index every time the server boots (via @PostConstruct method)

Comment: What else is different between dev/prod? Don't you use WAR files locally in DEV?

Comment: I do use WAR files locally as well.  I use the same web server (tomcat 6), the same database (mysql 5.5), the same WAR files between DEV and PROD.  I really don't understand why this is happening

Comment: Log the SQL generated and verify if there is a change in SQL by Hibernate, otherwise there is no reason it shows a different datasets.

Comment: I added `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.search=DEBUG` to my log properties, but didn't notice any difference in log output between DEV and PROD.

Comment: Can you post your config from both machines for hibernate.search.default.directory_provider and hibernate.search.default.indexBase and hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy ?

Comment: @MatBanik my directory_provider/indexBase values are identical for both DEV and PROD and can be seen under by `persistance.xml` file above.  Note that I did not specify any configuration for `hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy`

Comment: Are you using the same MySQL versions on both environments wit the same credentials, also did you verify that jdk in both environments is identical to the dot?

Comment: MySQL Dev: 5.5.28, MySQL PROD: 5.5.32.  My JDKs were not in sync, so I rolled my PROD back from 1.7 to 1.6.0_23-b05, my DEV JDK is 1.6.0_23-b05.  Still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the actual location where my software was looking for the indexBase was incorrect.

When I looked through the logs, I noticed that it was referring to two different locations when loading the indexBase.

One location that Hibernate Search was loading this indexBase was from "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/tmp/indexes", then a little later on in the logs (during the startup phase) I saw that it was also loading from the place I had set it to in my persistence.xml file ("C:/lucene/indexes").

So realizing this, I just changed the location in my persistence.xml file to match the location that it was (for some reason) also looking.  Once those two matched up, BINGO, everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just blind shot, if possible make your DEV env point to the PROD DB to see if you get the results that you're expecting.
Only to discard and be 100% sure that you're in front of the real problem :)

Comment: This is indeed a great idea, as I'd want to not only point to the DB but I'd want to point my DEV code to the PROD lucene indexes (that'll really tell me what's what).  However, I don't really know how to accomplish this.  I'm using a windows based VPS for my PROD machine, do you know of an easy way to share folders over the interwebs?  I tried using LogMeIn Hamachi with no luck

Comment: I was doing a quick research, but I do not know an easy way to achieve that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that in your persistence.xml configuration that you're under Mysql. Googling some sql concepts  about same queries in different environments I found that exists a cached mysql resultset from same queries, but this cached maybe changes depending on new variables from the environment like charset. Also you can disable this feature from your Mysql server.

## Cited from Hibernate In Action - Bauer, C. King, G. Page 55 (Section 2.4.3 Logging)

But, especially in the face of *asynchronous* behavior, debugging Hibernate can quickly
get you lost. You can use logging to get a view of Hibernate’s internals.
We’ve already mentioned the *hibernate.show_sql* configuration parameter,
which is usually the first port of call when **troubleshooting**. Sometimes the SQL
alone is insufficient; in that case, you must dig a little *deeper*.
Hibernate logs all interesting events using Apache *commons-logging*, a thin
abstraction layer that directs output to either Apache **log4j** (if you put *log4j.jar*
in your classpath) or *JDK1.4* logging (if you’re running under JDK1.4 or above and
log4j isn’t present). We recommend **log4j**, since it’s more mature, more popular,
and under more active development.
To see any output from **log4j**, you’ll need a file named *log4j.properties* in your
classpath (right next to *hibernate.properties* or *hibernate.cfg.xml*). This example
directs all log messages to the console:

### direct log messages to stdout ###

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

### root logger option ###

```
log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout
```

### Hibernate logging options ###

```
log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate=info
```

### log JDBC bind parameters ###

```
log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate.type=info
```

### log PreparedStatement cache activity ###

```
log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate.ps.PreparedStatementCache=info
```

With this configuration, you won’t see many log messages at runtime. Replacing
info with debug for the *log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate* category will reveal the
inner workings of Hibernate. Make sure you don’t do this in a production environment—
writing the log will be much slower than the actual database access.
Finally, you have the hibernate.properties, hibernate.cfg.xml, and
log4j.properties configuration files.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, but I'm using hibernate **search**, does this answer address the problem I've outlined correctly?

Comment: Sure, you're in the right way. I was just trying to give you some directions about asynchronous behavior.

Comment: I tried disabling the MySQL caching, but I believe it was already disabled.  In any case, I set everything to "off" and 0 but to no avail.  The problem is still there :(